How to store database uri in Flask config for SQLAlchemy?
I'm using Flask and SQLAlchemy (not flask-sqlalchemy).
I'm trying to get access to the flask config from my database code, but it's telling me that I'm not in an application context, probably because the app is not yet fully initialized.
I have app.py:
from flask import Flask

from root.views.calibration_views import calibration

nwm_app = Flask(__name__)
nwm_app.config.from_pyfile('myConfig.cfg')
print('config', nwm_app.config)

My calibration_views file imports database.py, which looks like this:
from sqlalchemy import URL, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

from flask import current_app as nwm_app


url = URL.create(
    drivername="postgresql",
    username="postgres",
    password="postgres",
    host="localhost",
    database="flask_test"
)
engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)

with nwm_app.app_context():
    print('config', nwm_app.config)


Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

I'm trying to get the config object using current_app, which avoids the Python error about circular imports, but I still get
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that was needed.

The current application. To solve this, set up an application context.

With app.app_context(). See the documentation for more information.

The nwm_app.app_context() was my attempt to fix it, but it had no effect
Part of me is wondering if the Flask config should really be used like this, even though they say you are allowed to put your own variables in there. It would be easy enough to just load a separate config file using normally Python behavior.

you need to ensure that the database-related code runs within the Flask application's context

modify your app.py to this
from flask import Flask

nwm_app = Flask(__name__)
nwm_app.config.from_pyfile('myConfig.cfg')
print('config', nwm_app.config)

# now you need to register your blueprints or views here
from root.views.calibration_views import calibration
nwm_app.register_blueprint(calibration)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nwm_app.run()


then your existing database.py
from sqlalchemy import URL, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from flask import current_app

def get_engine():
    url = URL.create(
        drivername="postgresql",
        username="postgres",
        password="postgres",
        host="localhost",
        database="flask_test"
    )
    return create_engine(url, echo=True)

def get_session():
    engine = get_engine()
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    return Session()

def get_config():
    with current_app.app_context():
        return current_app.config


now i added,this function called get_config to retrieve the configuration within the application context. also,the get-engine and get_session  are used to create the SQLAlchemy engine and session. This  is done in order to avoid creating the engine at the module level, which may cause issues if done outside the application context. now for your callibration_view.py,
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify
from root.database import get_session, get_config

calibration = Blueprint('calibration', __name__)

@calibration.route('/some_endpoint', methods=['GET'])
def some_view_function():
    session = get_session()
    config = get_config()
    
    # this is where i suggest you might perform your database operations here
    # for example:
    # results = session.query(SomeModel).all()
    
    return jsonify({'config': config})


so calling  with current_app.app_context():, i suppose you avoid the RuntimeError: Working outside of application context error.

Seems you have issues with how you set your project. The might be no app when you initialize the project. This leading to the error which you are getting. You should be able to access config without current_app or app_context.
One of the possible solutions is too leave in database.py this lines:
url = URL.create(
    drivername="postgresql",
    username="postgres",
    password="postgres",
    host="localhost",
    database="flask_test"
)
engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)

session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


This will allow to have a single point of access to db.
If you still require Flask configuration for setting up a database connection, you will need to store the session and database near the app.
Another possible solution would be modifying database.py like this:
engine = None
session = None


def init_db(app):
    global engine
    global session

    config = app.config
    # Use config here

    url = URL.create(
       drivername="postgresql",
       username="postgres",
       password="postgres",
       host="localhost",
       database="flask_test"
      )
    engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)
    session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


And in the app.py
This way you should avoid the circular imports.
from flask import Flask

from root.views.calibration_views import calibration

from database import init_db

nwm_app = Flask(__name__)
nwm_app.config.from_pyfile('myConfig.cfg')

init_db(app)


print('config', nwm_app.config)

There are other solutions without using globals variables but I hope these example will give a general understanding.
